# How to get LastLogon from ALL Domain Controllers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Thanks to the user Vesper I have been able to get this far with my Powershell script.

```
Get-ADDomainController -filter * | 
% {Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -server $_.name -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,LastLogon‌​,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "DC=REMOVEDFORANONYMITY,DC=com" | 
? {$_.EmployeeID -notlike "EXCLUDE" } | 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='Last‌​Logon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organizatio‌​n,Enabled | 
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\AD_Export_$($_.name).csv"}
```

However, when I run this script I get the following errors:
[image: error]

Is there something I am missing?

I am also wanting to make it to where not only does it grab LastLogon, but also grab LastLogonTimeStamp and then have is use whichever is the most recent. My Powershell knowledge is very small, can anyone add to my script what is needed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have pasted the `LastLogon,` part of the `Properties` argument from somewhere.

There are two zero-width unicode characters (`U+200C` and `U+200B`) between `LastLogon` and `,`.

Delete it and rewrite it by hand

Comment: Awesome, it works to an extent. It does exactly what is says, but now I need to make it so that it combines all of the exported csv files and keeps the most recent logon time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my powershell code for that. Just use or adapt it to your needs.

```ps
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$properties = ("Name", "SamAccountName", "mail", "lastLogon", "manager", "company", "createTimeStamp", "department", "logonCount", "pwdLastSet", "userPrincipalName", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "employeeID", "accountExpires", "division", "msDS-ResultantPSO")
$users = @{}

foreach ($hostname in (Get-ADDomainController -Filter { IsReadOnly -eq $false } ).HostName) {
    foreach ($user in (Get-ADUser -Server $hostname -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -properties $properties | Select-Object $properties)) {
        if ( $users.Item($user.SamAccountName)) {
            If ( $user.lastLogon -gt $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon ) { $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon = $user.lastLogon }
            $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).logonCount += $user.logonCount
        }
        else {
            $users.Add( $user.SamAccountName, $user )
        }
    }
}

$hostname = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -NextClosestSite).HostName
foreach ( $user in $users.Values ) {
    if ( $user.lastLogon ) { $user.lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.lastLogon) }
    if ( $user.pwdLastSet ) { $user.pwdLastSet = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet) }
    if ( $user.accountExpires -eq "9223372036854775807" -or $user.accountExpires -eq "0" ) { $user.accountExpires = "never expires" }
    else {
        $user.accountExpires = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.accountExpires) 
    }
    if ( $user.manager ) { $user.manager = (Get-ADUser $user.manager -Server "$hostname" -properties Name ).Name }
}

$users.Values | Export-Csv -Path C:\ins\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```